# Monitor directory content change

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script, and I'd like to monitor file changes into a directory (adding, deleting and renaming) and performing different action accordingly.

Is there a way to do that directly from my script (aside from periodically `ls` the directory and make `diff`s)?

Comment: [read about inotify](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CJcBEBYwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com%2Fdeveloperworks%2Flinux%2Flibrary%2Fl-ubuntu-inotify%2Findex.html&ei=_zCqT8mdMK3O4QTLnJSTCQ&usg=AFQjCNEbLpsLtRsvkJcEaDdVsZ8g5WmEhQ&sig2=HVCESNaEHgJrT6ENcrI7xA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `inotifywait` command (assuming your distribution supports inotify, which most do):

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%f' -e modify -e move -e create -e delete ~/test | while read line
do
    echo "File: $line"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. If you are allowed to do it only in **bash**, then you can generate a md5sum on directory contents. Probably you can have file-name,modify-time,inode-modify-time etc in that directory.